# Proving set theory subsets using element argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How do you even prove a set theory subset statement using element argument? I simply just can't find any relevance to the question with the notes i was studying.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

> (A - B) ∩ (C - B) subset of (A ∩ C) - B

The only definition i have is

> x element of A - B is logically equivalent to ( x element of A and x
>   not element of B)

If i were to sub in the definition, it would lead me to nowhere where i can use whatever law there is in set theory.

This discrete mathematics is way different from the typical maths i have been doing since young. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$x\in(A-B)\cap (C-B) $$
is equivalent to
$$x\in A-B\quad \land \quad x\in C-B $$
and so to
$$(x\in A \land x\notin B)\land (x\in C\land x\notin B). $$
Form this you want to show that $x\in(A\cap C)-B$, or equivalently, that
$$(x\in A\land x\in C)\land x\notin B. $$
I guess you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by using strict definitions of subsets:

$A \subset B$ is saying $\forall x\in A$ $x\in B$

So:

Let $x\in (A-B)\cap(C-B)$

Then $x\in (A-B)$ and $x\in(C-B)$

Then $x\in A\cap C$ and $x\notin (A\cap C)\cap B$ otherwise contradiction to the assumption $x\in (A-B)\cap(C-B)$

Then $x\in (A\cap C)-B$

Comment: After "Then $x\in (A-B)$ and $x\in (C-B)$", I think it's clearer to just write: "Then $x\in A$, $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$" or "Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, and $x\in C$ and $x\notin B$."

Answer (score 0):

As part of gaining deeper insights I'm trying to answer questions so that errors in my reasoning will hopefully be pointed out.

To proof using the element argument:

${(A-B)\cup(C-B) \subseteq (A \cup C)-B}$

We start as follows

${x \in (A-B)\cap(C-B)}$

${x \in (A \cap \overline{B})\cap(C\cap\overline{B}) }$ difference law

${(x \in A \land x \in \overline{B}) \land (x \in C \land x \in \overline{B})}$ def union

${(x \in A \land x \in C) \land (x \in \overline{B} \land x \in \overline{B})}$ associative + commutative laws

${(x \in A \land x \in C) \land x \in \overline{B}}$ idempotency law

${x \in (A \cap C) \cap \overline{B}}$ def intersection

${x \in (A \cap C)-B}$ difference law

And that concludes the proof.

This is the long version of what Hagen von Eitzen has given.

Answer (score 0):

**[** (A - B) ∩ (C - B) **] ⊆ [** (A ∩ C) - B **]**

steps:

1.
∈(−)∩(C−)

2.

(a) ∈(−) and
(b) ∈(C−)

3.

From (a) ∈ and x∉B

From (b) ∈C and x∉B

4.
Hence, ∈ and ∈C and x∉B are true.

5.
By definition of intersection: ∈(∩C) and x∉B

6.
By definition of set difference: ∈(∩C)-B

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).